# Understanding a* for Java / processing

Tags: java, algorithm, processing

I am trying to learn the a* algorithm, the Dijkstra one too. Yesterday I found a working example for processing, which I thought was easily coded. I looked at the content of the project but i didn't see any method to get the steps or to save the way to the target in an Array... 
So here finally are my questions:

1. To implement such a pathfinding system into a game like pacman, there needs to be a Array, where the steps or the way will be saved right?
2. Because I don't really know yet how pathfinding is used... How is it possible that the enemy (ghost) moves to the target by looking at the Array?

If some one wants to see the code of the algorithm:

```
int[][] findPath () { int[][]done=asArray(); done[fR][fC] = 0;int counter = 0;while (true) { boolean foundOne = false; for (int i = 0; i < copyArray.length; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < copyArray[0].length; j++) { if (done[i][j] == counter) { foundOne = true; if (isValid(done, i-1, j, counter+1)) done[i-1][j] = counter + 1; if (isValid(done, i+1, j, counter+1)) done[i+1][j] = counter + 1; if (isValid(done, i, j-1, counter+1)) done[i][j-1] = counter + 1; if (isValid(done, i, j+1, counter+1)) done[i][j+1] = counter + 1; } } } counter ++; if (!foundOne) break; } for (int i = 0; i < copyArray.length; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < copyArray[0].length; j++) { //print ( done[i][j] + "\t" ); } println (); } return done; } ArrayList getPath(int[][] flood) { if (flood[sR][sC] == -1) return null; ArrayList path = new ArrayList(); int cR = sR, cC = sC; while (true) { if (cR == fR && cC == fC) { return path; } if (isValid(flood, cR-1, cC)) { if (flood[cR-1][cC] < flood[cR][cC]) { cR = cR-1; cC = cC; PVector spot = new PVector (cR, cC); path.add (spot); continue; } } if (isValid(flood, cR+1, cC)) { if (flood[cR+1][cC] < flood[cR][cC]) { cR = cR+1; cC = cC; PVector spot = new PVector (cR, cC); path.add (spot); continue; } } if (isValid(flood, cR, cC-1)) { if (flood[cR][cC-1] < flood[cR][cC]) { cR = cR; cC = cC-1; PVector spot = new PVector (cR, cC); path.add (spot); continue; } } if (isValid(flood, cR, cC+1)) { if (flood[cR][cC+1] < flood[cR][cC]) { cR = cR; cC = cC+1; PVector spot = new PVector (cR, cC); path.add (spot); continue; } } } } boolean isValid (int[][] arr, int r, int c, int count) { if (r < 0 || r >= rows) return false; if (c < 0 || c >= cols) return false; if (arr[r][c] == -2) return false; if (arr[r][c] <= count && arr[r][c] != -1) return false; return true; } boolean isValid (int[][] arr, int r, int c) { if (r < 0 || r >= rows) return false; if (c < 0 || c >= cols) return false; if (arr[r][c] == -2) return false; return true; } int[][] asArray () { int[][] res = new int[rows][cols]; for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) { if (maze[i][j].type != 1) res[i][j] = -1; else res[i][j] = -2; } } return res; } int maxValIn2D (int[][] look) { int mx = 0; for (int i = 0; i < look.length; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < look[i].length; j++) { mx = look[i][j] > mx ? look[i][j] : mx; } } return mx; } int wrapAround (int low, int high, int data) { return (data >= low && data <= high) ? data : (data < low ? high - (low - data - 1) : low + (data - high - 1)); //LOL }
```

Main File :

```
int[][] testArray2 = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};int[][] copyArray = new int[testArray2.length][testArray2[0].length];Tile[][] maze; int rows; int cols; int lastMilli = 0; int[][] mapData; ArrayList path; int state; boolean found; boolean isNeeded = false; int sR, sC, fR, fC; void setup() { size (600, 600); background (255); arrayCopy(testArray2,copyArray); path = new ArrayList<Integer>(); maze = new Tile[copyArray.length][copyArray[0].length]; for (int i = 0; i < copyArray.length; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < copyArray[0].length; j++) { // was bedeuted 0 ?? if(copyArray[i][j] == 0 || copyArray[i][j] == 2) { maze[i][j] = new Tile(i, j, 0); } if(copyArray[i][j] == 1 ) { maze[i][j] = new Tile(i, j, 1); } } rows = copyArray.length; cols = copyArray[0].length; } state = 0; // sind die koordinaten des startes, im array sR = 4; sC = 5; // sind die koordinaten des zieles, im array fR = 8; fC = 8; found = true; noStroke(); } void draw() { background (255); if (!found && sR != -1 && sC != -1 && fR != 1 && fC != -1) { found = true; mapData = findPath(); path = getPath(mapData); } noStroke (); // mahlt nur das array for (int i = 0; i < copyArray.length; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < copyArray[0].length; j++) { switch(maze[i][j].type) { case 0:if (mapData != null) { if (mapData[i][j]==-1) { fill (255); } else { colorMode (HSB); fill (160, map(mapData[i][j], 0, maxValIn2D(mapData), 0, 255), 255); colorMode (RGB); } } else { fill (255); } break; case 1: fill (0); break; case 2: fill (0, 255, 0); break; case 3: fill (255, 0, 0); break; case 4: fill (64, 64, 255); break; } if (path != null) { for (Object o : path) { PVector p = (PVector)o; // zeigt den gelben weg an if (p.x == i && p.y == j && !(p.x == fR && p.y == fC)) { fill (255, 255, 0); println(p.x+" "+p.y); } } } rect ((width/cols) * j, (height/rows) * i, width/cols, height/rows); } } switch (state) { case 0: stroke (128); break; case 1: stroke (0, 255, 0); break; case 2: stroke (255, 0, 0); break; } noFill (); int row = (int) map (mouseY, 0, height, 0, rows); int col = (int) map (mouseX, 0, width, 0, cols); rect ((width/cols) * col, (height/rows) * row, width/cols, height/rows); maze[sR][sC].type = 2; maze[fR][fC].type = 3; milli(2500); found = false; for(int i = 0; i< path.size();i++) { print(path.get(i)); } } void milli(int intervall) { if(millis()>lastMilli+intervall)//been at least 200 millis { lastMilli=millis(); //wpdate the last time we did anything //println("Millis is Running"); } }
```

I know maybe it's a lot and that there are 2 questions.

Comment: When you post a question, make sure it is completely understandable. As of right now it is complete gibberish.

Comment: I know, because of that i Edited that i Wrote it on mobile and I will change that soon as possible

Comment: I don't get Your random Capitalization - but I did a first pass edit. You also need to format your code, which I'm not going to spend time doing. I think it's still pretty unclear what you're asking though.

Comment: Also, links to descriptions of the algorithms you're talking about would be helpful as well, for a starter.

Comment: I really think im Not Good at asking such questions... I only wanna know, how i can use that pathfinding Code to move an Object to the pathfind target :( maybe the Code is Confusing yeah.

Comment: Agree with the other comments regarding the quality of your question.  Additionally, I believe a simple Google search would probably have yielded you some insight, for example: http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior - hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying, and I applaud you for that.

But you're approaching this a bit backwards: you don't understand an algorithm by looking at code first. You understand an algorithm by starting with plain old English, and the **last** step is to look at (or write) code.

If you want to understand these algorithms, the first thing you need to do is read about them- wikipedia is a good place to start. When you think you've understood what you've read, then the next step is to write them out **in your own words** as a set of steps. Do this in English- not in code; not even in pseudocode.

Pretend you have a very dumb friend who has no idea what A* or Dijkstra is. Write out a list of steps that your friend could follow in order to accomplish one of those algorithms. Remember how dumb your friend is, so make sure each step is as small as possible! Break those steps down into smaller sub-steps whenever you can.

Seriously, do this in real life. Use some graph paper to draw a maze, and give that maze to somebody else along with the list of steps you've written out. Have them follow your steps to get out of the maze.

When you have those steps written out, that's the algorithm you can start thinking about turning into code.

If you get stuck on a specific step, that's what Stack Overflow is for. But right now your question is still way too broad to give you a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks man :) Thats a helpfull answer. Soo But the steps Need to be saved somewhere right? That the AI can chase the Player...

Comment: @gnr Here's the golden rule of programming: start smaller, and break your problem down into smaller steps. I wouldn't worry too much about the AI, or the player. Start smaller by writing some simple code that finds a path from point A to point B. Write that in its own example project, that way if you get stuck you can post it as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you know that the ghosts in Pac-Man don't actually find a path to Pac-Man, right? :p

Comment: Ok ill give it a try :) yeah sure they got "states" so they move random and every idk how many sec they trigger the pacman, so they move in His Direction, then they move random again and so on... Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @gnr Yeah, exactly. The ghosts don't really look for a path, they just go up if Pac-Man is above them, left if Pac-Man is to the left, etc. Actually it's a little more interesting than that (each ghost has its own rules), but the point is that you shouldn't make it overly complicated if you don't have to!